# T-SQL windowing functions - counting the a history

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, partition, rowcount

I want to rowcount a booking history, everytime I got an Cancellation that booking is finished and a new one started. "VER_INTERCODE" is my booking identifier, but I can't guarantee once closed to be used again.
Finally I want to count like "VER_MYTARGET", "foo" is my best try.

[image: My example]

```
 CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
    [VER_ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [VER_COMPANYCODE] CHAR(4),
    [VER_ORDERNUMMER] CHAR(17),
    [VER_PERIOD] INT,
    [VER_INTERCODE] CHAR(12),
    [VER_STATE] VARCHAR(50),
    [VER_MYTARGET] INT,
)
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202009, 'CP9598749ZZF', '04-WIP', 4),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202010, 'CP9598749ZZF', '04-WIP', 4),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202011, 'CP9598749ZZF', '04-WIP', 4),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202012, 'CP9598749ZZF', '06-CIA-Cancel', 4),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202012, 'CP959874111F', '03-STANDARD_CP', 3),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202012, 'CP959874111F', '06-DWH-BOOKING', 3),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202101, 'CP959874111F', '06-DWH-Cancel', 3),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202101, 'CP9598749ZZF', '06-CIA-BOOKING', 2),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202102, 'CP9598749ZZF', '04-WIP', 2),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202103, 'CP9598749ZZF', '06-CIA-Cancel', 2),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202103, 'CP959874111F', '06-DWH-BOOKING', 1),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202104, 'CP959874111F', '07-DWH-Cancel', 1),
('3187', '80202009093964369', 202104, 'CP959874000F', '07-DWH-BOOKING', 0)

--DROP TABLE #temptable

SELECT *,
       COUNT(   CASE
                    WHEN V.VER_STATE IN ( '06-CIA-Cancel', '06-DWH-Cancel' ) THEN
                        1
                END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY V.VER_COMPANYCODE,
                                 V.VER_ORDERNUMMER,
                                 V.VER_INTERCODE
                    ORDER BY V.VER_PERIOD DESC,
                             V.VER_STATE DESC
                   ) AS foo
FROM #temptable V
ORDER BY 1
```

Thanks for your help, I appreciate.

Comment: What do the symbols mean, for example `06` or `07` and `DWH` or `CIA`? Are we just looking for anything ending with `Cancel`? And why would you store multiple pieces of info in one column?

Comment: @Charlieface That symbols just represent a status - 06,07, DWH, CIA doesn’t mean anything. Only if the status includes the substring "cancel" the booking is closed. 

This table is a booking history and each booking has a status fixed for that time - It makes sense to me so far.

Comment: Then do you not want the `COUNT` to be `COUNT(CASE WHEN V.VER_STATE LIKE '%CANCEL' THEN 1 END) OVER...`? And then you just put the whole thing in a subquery/derived table and group by that count in the outer query? (I was just trying to say earlier, that good DB design is to keep one piece of info in each column)

Comment: Dear @Charlieface, could you give me an example please. I don't know how to manage windowfunction and group by in one statement.

Comment: @BobAustralia why would there be a difference between the green and yellow bookings in your screenshot? Your attempt seems to count them the same, whereas your target counts them differently; which is correct?